# LINQ Count and Group by different Columns

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

id'like to count how many documents a User edited or created. Therefore I have a Datatable which contains the information sth. like this:

```
Input
DocumentName | ModifiedBy | CreatedBy
 a              Frank         Frank
 b              Mike          Frank
 c              John          Mike
```

That should be the Output:

```
Name   DocumentsModified(Total)  DocumentsCreated(Total)
Frank      1                        2
Mike       1                        1
John       1                        0
```

So what it did to count all documents a person edited, is the following

```
var query = from queryResult in resultTable.AsEnumerable()
group queryResult by queryResult.Field<string>("ModifiedBy") into rowGroup
select new 
{
    Name = rowGroup.Key, ModifiedDocuments = rowGroup.Count()
};
```

This works fine. Now i have to count also the values of the column "Creator". Is this possible and if so, how would i do that? OK, i could iterate over the table, but it would be nice to accomplish this in the LinQ query.

I tried to use "group queryResult by new {}" but i'm not sure if i'm on the right track.

Comment: What is the expected output?  Do you want a list of names of who the creators were for all of the documents a person modified?  Do you just want the count of the distinct creators for each of the documents each person modified?  Do you want just the count of the documents each person created?  Sample input/output would help as well.

Comment: @Servy: Thanks for your reply, I added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're best bet would be to just query for created and modified separately and then combine the results with a join.

```
var modifiedCount = from queryResult in resultTable.AsEnumerable()
group queryResult by queryResult.Field<string>("ModifiedBy") into rowGroup
select new 
{
    Name = rowGroup.Key, ModifiedDocuments = rowGroup.Count()
};

var createdCount = from queryResult in resultTable.AsEnumerable()
group queryResult by queryResult.Field<string>("CreatedBy") into rowGroup
select new 
{
    Name = rowGroup.Key, CreatedDocuments = rowGroup.Count()
};

var finalResult = from first in modifiedCount 
                  join second in createdCount
                  on first.Name equal second.Name
                  select new 
                  {
                     first.Name,
                     first.ModifiedDocuments,
                     second.CreatedDocuments 
                  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use the same method with `CreatedBy`?

```
var query2 = from queryResult in resultTable.AsEnumerable()
group queryResult by queryResult.Field<string>("CreatedBy") into rowGroup
select new 
{
    Name = rowGroup.Key, ModifiedDocuments = rowGroup.Count()
};
```

And then use your 2 queries sorted by Name.

Comment: If i understand you right, this leads in the same direction as the reply of Servy? Works fine for me, thanks for your answer!